# How can i use a Vector of Struct containing vector<Mat>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, struct

I tried to declare a struct,

```
struct Sample {
    int classLabel[2];
    vector<Mat> image; 
};
```

Now i want to use it, i initialize it as

```
Sample sample1;
```

and save 5 images in `sample1`, and created another `Sample sample2` and saved another 5 images.
Now i want to save these two samples in a vector of `Sample`. I declared:

```
vector<Sample> samples;
```

now when i try to push_back sample1 and sample2 in samples

```
samples.push_back(sample1);
samples.push_back(sample2);
```

it gives me nothing. the samples shows as `samples[2]` but includes nothing with question marks infront of `classLabel=???` and `image=????`

Can any body guide me where i am doing mistake. How can i make it useable. i mean properly save that struct `sample1` and `sample2` in `samples`. 
Will be thankful. 
Regards

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<Sample> samples;
samples.push_back(sample1);
samples.push_back(sample2);
```

After this, the size of `samples` is 2. So you can only access `samples[0]` and `samples[1]`, not `samples[2]`.

---

As commented by @sammy, variables in `Watch` may show incorrect values in VS.

To make it work, you may want to follow the following steps:

1. Check if the application and its dependencies (if required) are built in **debug** mode.
2. Ensure the Optimization is disable. Use the **`/Od`** option when compiling.
3. **Struct Member Alignment**. When there are a bunch of projects compiled together, with varying values for this field inside the projects could cause invalid display values. Reset to  **Default**  value on all of the projects.The value is under **Configuration Properties-> C/C++ ->Code Generation -> Struct Member Alignment**.

Check out [here](http://sajive.blogspot.hk/2012/04/visual-studio-shows-incorrect-values.html) for more info.

---

**Edit:** For your code in the comment:

```
sample1.classlabel[0] = 0; 
sample1.classlabel[1]=1;
vector<Mat> temp; 
temp.push_back(img1); 
temp.push_back(img2); 
temp.push_back(img3); 
sample1.image=temp; 

sample2.classlabel[0] = 0; 
sample2.classlabel[1]=1; 
vector<Mat> temp1; 
temp.push_back(img5);         // problem
temp.push_back(img6);         // problem
temp.push_back(img7);         // problem
sample2.image=temp1; 

samples.push_back(sample1); 
samples.push_back(sample2);
```

The 3 problem lines should change to

```
temp1.push_back(img5);
temp1.push_back(img6);
temp1.push_back(img7);
```

Comment: You did not understood, or may be i did mistake in explaining, the size is shown as samples[2]. But if you acess samples[0] or samples[1] it shows classlabel=??? and image=????.

Comment: @khan In Debug or in Release mode? And you may need to share your full code here.

Comment: in debug,               sample1.classlabel[0] = 0;
   sample1.classlabel[1]=1;    vector<Mat> temp;        temp.push_back(img1);  temp.push_back(img2); temp.push_back(img3);                                   sample1.image=temp;                                     sample2.classlabel[0] = 0; 
sample2.classlabel[1]=1;                                     vector<Mat> temp1;        temp.push_back(img5);temp.push_back(img6);temp.push_back(img7);         sample2.image=temp1;                        samples.push_back(sample1);                  samples.push_back(sample2);

Comment: @khan What's `sample`? Please share your full code so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @khan It's probably working fine - sometimes the debugger cannot display complex objects. But their value is correct. That ???? only means it cannot display it in debugger, but nothing else

Comment: @khan Better post your code in the question, not in the comment.

Comment: Thanks yeah you are right... Sammy, The data is saved in it but shown as ?????...